# Does Sub Power Up affect Special Bomb Launcher?

Tags: splatoon-2

According to Splatoon wikia, [Special Power Up](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Special_Power_Up) improves the performance of special weapons, and for Bomb Launchers it only says:

> Increases duration

So, knowing that [Sub Power Up](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Sub_Power_Up) perk increases bomb velocity and travel distance, does it affects also bombs thrown while Bomb Launcher special weapon is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub power up does affect bomb launchers, but only under certain conditions. [This Squidboard thread](https://squidboards.com/threads/does-sub-power-up-affect-bomb-launcher.32784/) says it better than I can:

> > > Does Sub Power Up affect Bomb Launcher?
> >
> > Yes, it does but only if you throw it at max range. If you hold R your
> >     inkling will throw them at maximum range/speed which will be affected
> >     by Sub-Power Up while the R button-mashing that most people use will
> >     not be affected by Sub Power Up.

It will probably be more effective to use special power up because then you don't have to worry about holding R. You'll be able to get more bombs out, ink more turf, and it's easier to trap someone with your bombs if you're mashing R.

Comment: Thank you. I've found what I need by myself, but since you're the only one who answered I accept it.